# Comparing el.text() === "string" results in false, even when element contains "string"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, the else and not the if is always executed even though the alert tells me that `state` does in fact contain the string `payment`.

```
var state = $('.check-state').text();
alert(state); // payment
if (state === "payment")
    alert('hello');
else
    alert('not match')
```

Why is that?

Comment: Trim spaces, `var state = $.trim($('.check-state').text());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your HTML look sort of like this:

```
<div class="check-state">
    payment
</div>
```

Then the `.text()` will return everything between the `>` and the `<`, including the whitespace. So what you get is `"\n    payment\n"`, not `"payment"`.

The solution is to trim the whitespace away, using jQuerys [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
var state = $.trim($('.check-state').text());
```

On a side note, I would recommend you to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging. In most browsers, that would have allowed you to detect where the error was since you would have clearly seen the whitespace.